# Spring batch example for single job to read from a table then split the results by type and process in parallel

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Each parallel step will create a file, if all succeed then these files will be moved together to an output folder. If any of these steps fail then none of the files will go to the output folder and the whole job is failed. Help with / code example much appreciated for batch noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> read from a table then split the results by type and process in parallel

You can partition data by type using a partition step. Partitions will be processed in parallel and each partition creates a file. Then you add step after the partition step to clean up the files if any of the partitions fail. Here is a quick example you can try:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.Partitioner;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class PartitionJobSample {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {

        return steps.get("step1")
                .partitioner(workerStep().getName(), partitioner())
                .step(workerStep())
                .gridSize(3)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }

    @Bean
    public Partitioner partitioner() {
        return gridSize -> {
            Map<String, ExecutionContext> map = new HashMap<>(gridSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
                ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
                executionContext.put("data", "data" + i);
                String key = "partition" + i;
                map.put(key, executionContext);
            }
            return map;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Step workerStep() {
        return steps.get("workerStep")
                .tasklet(getTasklet(null))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Tasklet getTasklet(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['data']}") String partitionData) {
        return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            if (partitionData.equals("data2")) {
                throw new Exception("Boom!");
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " processing partitionData = " + partitionData);
            Files.createFile(Paths.get(partitionData + ".txt"));
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Step moveFilesStep() {
        return steps.get("moveFilesStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("moveFilesStep");
                    // add code to move files where needed
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step cleanupFilesStep() {
        return steps.get("cleanupFilesStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("cleaning up..");
                    deleteFiles();
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                    .flow(step1()).on("FAILED").to(cleanupFilesStep())
                    .from(step1()).on("*").to(moveFilesStep())
                    .from(moveFilesStep()).on("*").end()
                    .from(cleanupFilesStep()).on("*").fail()
                    .build()
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        deleteFiles();
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(PartitionJobSample.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

    private static void deleteFiles() throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("data" + i + ".txt"));
        }
    }

}
```

This example creates 3 dummy partitions ("data0", "data1" and "data2"). Each partition will create a file. If all partitions finish correctly, you will have three files "data0.txt", "data1.txt" and "data2.txt" which will be moved in the `moveFilesStep.`

Now let make one of the partitions fail, for example the second partition:

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Tasklet getTasklet(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['data']}") String partitionData) {
        return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            if (partitionData.equals("data2")) {
                throw new Exception("Boom!");
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " processing partitionData = " + partitionData);
            Files.createFile(Paths.get(partitionData + ".txt"));
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }
```

In this case, the `cleanupFilesStep` will be triggered and will delete all files.

Hope this helps.